# Using an ItemsControl in a grouped ListView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I'm trying to use an `ItemsControl` -instead of an `ItemsPresenter`- to render the Items of a `GroupItem` but can't find out the right Property to bind to.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
 <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
  <ItemsControl 
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=??}"/>
   <!--<ItemsPresenter  />-->
 </Expander>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Whatever property I'm using does show nothing
so what's the Property of a GroupItem to use as an ItemsSource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not able to check right this second, is it `GroupItems`?

Comment: @Chris Tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each group is represented by an instance of [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which publishes `Items` property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
   <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
   </Expander>
</ControlTemplate>
```